# Unicode character support

Tags: c#, .net, character-encoding

Usually in C++ we use `wchar_t` and `wstring` for Unicode wide characters and strings. Do we have anything like this in C#?

To make things simple let me put it this way:

If I'm simply converting C++ code to C# so what should I use in place of `wchar_t` and `wstring` ?
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use string :)

> The string type represents a sequence of zero or more Unicode characters. string is an alias for String in the .NET Framework.

Taken from [string (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx)

Comment: Calling them “Unicode characters” is a very confusing way to say it. They're actually a sequence of UTF-16 code units (which is not the same as Unicode code points). `wchar_t` is commonly defined this way too, but it doesn't have to.